# Crystal Report - Query in formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I have formula,

## stringvar q1;

## stringvar query;

## q1 := "SELECT SHOW_CERT FROM C_SPEC_DELTA_REPORT_VIEW X WHERE X.VERSION = (select CONSTANT_VALUE from LIMS_CONSTANTS where name ='C_PRODUCT_VERSION1_DELTA') AND X.GRADE = ' " + {Command.GRADE} + " ' AND X.SAMPLING_POINT = ' " + {Command.SAMPLING_POINT} + " ' AND X.COMPONENT = ' " + {Command.COMPONENT} + " ')"

## query := q1;

## SQL( query )

Here, in the {command.COMPONENT} field, it the value in more than 30 Characters, my report execution is failing.

Is there is any length constraint? If Yes, how to extend it.

The length of the COMPONENT field is 160 characters in the DB.

Need your help!!!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Report is crashing. No error is reported.

Comment: are you able to get the data if you fire same query in DB?

Comment: Yes. Am able to get the data from DB.